# super init constructor in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I used to work with Objective-c using the following code in my class NSObject constructor :

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init] ;
    return self;
}
```

How do I use it in Swift?

I tried to do this:

```
override init() {
    self = super.init()
    return self;
}
```

I'm getting two errors:

```
cannot assign value self is immutable
nil is the only return value permitted in this initializer
```

Comment: you just do `super.init()`.

Comment: Did you read the appropriate chapter in the free Swift Language book? I thought it was all explained there.

Comment: But you know that the `init` as written above in Objective-C is completely useless, right?

Comment: @pre yep i know that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't assign to `self` in Swift.  Just use

```
super.init()
```

You also don't return anything.  Constructors are of type void (in C lingo).

Answer (score 11):

The Swift initialization sequence has a little bit difference from Objective-C,

```
class BaseClass {
    var value : String
    init () {
        value = "hello"
    }
}
```

the subclass below.

```
class SubClass : BaseClass {
    var subVar : String
    let subInt : Int

    override init() {
        subVar = "world"
        subInt = 2015
        super.init()
        value = "hello world 2015" // optional, change the value of superclass
    }

}
```

The initialization sequence is:

1. Initialize subclass's var or let,
2. Call super.init(), if the class has a super class,
3. Change value of superclass, if you wanna do that.

I think your code:

```
override init() {
    self = super.init()  //just call super.init(), do not assign it to self
    return self;         //it is unnecessary to return self
}
```

We must remember initialize all of the var or let in the class.

Comment: You have to initialize the super's stored properties first by calling `super.init…()` and then the subclass' stored properties.

Comment: Actually,if we call the <br\>    super.init() firstly,the compiler will prompt a error "Property 'self.subVar' not initialized at super.init call" and "Immutable value 'self.subInt' may only be initialized once". If you try it,you'll see. @Amin Negm-Awad

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, you don't assign or return `self`. In addition, you need to call `super.init()` **after** custom initialization. I.e., if your Objective-C code looked something like:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        someProperty = 42;
    }
}
```

then the equivalent in Swift would be

```
init() {
    self.someProperty = 42
    super.init()
}
```

The reason for this is stated in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html):

> **Safety check 1** A designated initializer must ensure that all of the
>   properties introduced by its class are initialized before it delegates
>   up to a superclass initializer.
>
> As mentioned above, the memory for an object is only considered fully
>   initialized once the initial state of all of its stored properties is
>   known. In order for this rule to be satisfied, a designated
>   initializer must make sure that all of its own properties are
>   initialized before it hands off up the chain.

Comment: Actually, `super.init()` should be called ASAP, especially in Swift.  The rule is that the super-state (the state provided by superclasses) should be initialized first.  Obviously this is not always possible or desired, but it should definitely be preferred.

Comment: @Avi right, but that "ASAP" is the end of the method most often than not… maybe I should've phrased in differently.

Comment: How is that true?  One of the reasons for subclassing is to override properties in the superclass.  If you init the super last, it may override the default value for properties you've already assigned.  Why would the default position for the call to `super.init()` be last?

Comment: Ah, I just reread Apple's doc, and actually you are correct.  No wonder Swift makes no sense to me.  (edit) It looks like we're both right.  For new properties, `super.init()` has to be after, for inherited properties, it must be before.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple document, the Swift Programming Language, about initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html). An example in the document.

```
class Bicycle: Vehicle {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        numberOfWheels = 2
    }
}
```